# CXF Webservice deployment IBM Websphere

Tags: websphere, jax-ws, saaj

I'm getting this error every time I try to deploy my web service client on WebSphere

```
SAAJ meta-factory com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.soap.SAAJMetaFactoryImpl 
incompatible with javax.xml.soap.SAAJMetaFactory
```

It appears IBM is trying to provide an implementation from their JAXWS engine that isn't compatible.  The `SAAJMetaFactory` is in the `saaj-impl` jar, which is in my class path, and since I am loading classes parent last, it should be the first one to get picked up.  I've tried disabling the IBM JAXWS engine in the manifest file by adding this line:

```
DisableIBMJAXWSEngine: true
```

No luck.  I even had the following JVM property added:

```
com.ibm.websphere.webservices.DisableIBMJAXWSEngine=true
```

No luck.  What else can I do?  This has been plaguing me for weeks now.

Comment: Check this http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PK93756 and  http://cxf.apache.org/docs/application-server-specific-configuration-guide.html#ApplicationServerSpecificConfigurationGuide-ForWebSphere6.1.0.29+,V7andV8 . Also double check that you have disabled IBM web service engine and set classloader to parent last.

Comment: I have the class loader set to parent last and I've added those variables discussed in the article.  I'm still receiving the error.  Is there a GUI way to disable the JAXWS engine in the Websphere console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by upgrading the solution to use Java 6.  The Java 6 runtime has a SAAJ implementation in it.  I no longer get the error I was getting.  I had to upgrade to newever versions of Spring (4.0.5 RELEASE) and CXF (2.7.11) as well.